# Balance Binary tree Coding

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

Hey guys I have just started to learn binary tree in my course and I was asked this question recently. Thanks to my unbelievably bad implementation and insufficient understanding of what the question is asking, I just simply have no idea how to tackle this. Please help me!!!

A binary tree T with n nodes is said to be h-balance if for any node u
in T, the difference between the heights of its two sub-trees is at most h, where h >= 0
is an integer. Assume that an empty tree has height -1. Suppose each node u has
three fields: u.lc points to u's left child and u.lc = NULL if u does not have a left
child; u.rc points to u's right child and u.rc = NULL if u does not have a right child;
u.height should be set to be the height of tree rooted at u.

(a) Given r that points to the root of the tree, design an algorithm in pseudo code
(or C/C++) that fills in the height of each node u in u:height.

(b) Suppose the height of each node u is stored in u.height, write an algorithm to
check if T is h-balanced. (Hint: modify algorithm designed in (a))

Answer (score 4):

This is not even pseudo code, but should help you a bit on the way.

It often makes a problem clearer if you state its conditions more formally:

a)

- The height of a leaf is -1
- The height of an internal node is one greater than the maximum of the heights of its two subtrees.

b)

- A leaf is h-balanced
- An internal node is h-balanced if and only if both its subtrees are h-balanced and the difference between their heights is at most h.

As you can see, both problems follow the same pattern: one leaf case, and a case that depends on the two subtrees.

This is the general form of recursing on binary trees:

```
void recurse(t)
{
    if (t is a leaf, i.e. an empty tree)
    {
       handle the leaf case
    }
    else
    {
        do something that depends on 
           recurse(left subtree of t) 
        and 
           recurse(right subtree of t)
    }
}
```

I'm leaving the rest of the solution as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm. Assume the node structure is declared as follows:

```
struct Node {
    Node *l;    // left child
    Node *r;    // right child
    int   h;    // subtree height
};
```

Then

```
void CalcHeights(Node *n)
{
    if(n != NULL)
    {
        CalcHeights(n->l);  // calc height in subtrees
        CalcHeights(n->r);
        int hl = n->l ? n->l->h : -1;   // read calculated heights
        int hr = n->r ? n->r->h : -1;

        n->h = (hl > hr ? hl : hr) + 1; // get the bigger one plus 1
    }
}

bool TestBalanced(Node const *n, int h)
{
    if(n != NULL)
    {
        if(! TestBalanced(n->l, h) || ! TestBalanced(n->r, h))
            return false;               // unbalanced subtree...

        int hl = n->l ? n->l->h : -1;   // get subtrees heights
        int hr = n->r ? n->r->h : -1;

        return abs(hl - hr) <= h;   // test the difference against H
    }
    return true;  // empty tree is balanced
}
```